# onClick para cambiar el State y no funciona

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un componente menu. Éste, via css cambia al típico menu del movil con la hamburguesa y la lista de los items en columna.

por default, como es obvio, solo se muestra la hamburguesa, y quiero que al hacer click en esta hamburguesa, agregue ciertas clases a ciertos divs, para que este se muestre.

Creo que no defino las constantes como debe de ser (creo que es el fallo), pero no sé como proceder.

os dejo el código del componente:

```
export class MenuComponent extends Component{


constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state  = {
           menuMobile: true
       }
   }
   openMenuMobile(){
       this.setState({menuMobile:false});
       console.log(this.state.menuMobile)
   }

render() {
    const clickedMenuToggle = this.state.menuMobile ? 'menu-toggle' : 'menu-toggle dark-menu';
    const clickedToggle = this.state.menuMobile ? 'toggle' : 'toggle opened';
    const clickedMenuMobile = this.state.menuMobile ? 'menu-mobile' : 'menu-mobile menu-mobile-opened';
    const clickedItemLi = this.state.menuMobile ? '' : 'item-li-opened';
    const clickedItemLia = this.state.menuMobile ? 'a-item-mobile' : 'a-item-mobile item-a-opened';

    return(
        <header>
            <div className={clickedMenuToggle}>
                <section className="content-mobile-menu">
                    <div className={clickedToggle}>
                        <div className="hamburger" onClick={this.openMenuMobile}>
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="ex">
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img className="logo-mobile" width="70" height="100" alt="Prrrcl Logo"
                         src={Logo} />
                    <div className="arrow-to-top">
                        <img
                            src="" alt={'Click to top'}/>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <ul className={clickedMenuMobile}>
                <li className={clickedItemLi}>
                    <Link to={'/home'} className={clickedItemLia}><span>home</span></Link>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <nav className="header-nav not--clickable">
                <ul className="ul-menu">
                    <ItemMenu url={'/'} children={'home'}/>
                    <ItemMenu url={'/projects'} children={'projects'}/>

                    <li>
                        <img id="logo--header" width="90" alt="Prrrcl Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+CjwhLS0gQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIElua3NjYXBlIChodHRwOi8vd3d3Lmlua3NjYXBlLm9yZy8pIC0tPgoKPHN2ZwogICB4bWxuczpkYz0iaHR0cDovL3B1cmwub3JnL2RjL2VsZW1lbnRzLzEuMS8iCiAgIHhtbG5zOmNjPSJodHRwOi8vY3JlYXRpdmVjb21tb25zLm9yZy9ucyMiCiAgIHhtbG5zOnJkZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS8wMi8yMi1yZGYtc3ludGF4LW5zIyIKICAgeG1sbnM6c3ZnPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIKICAgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIgogICB4bWxuczpzb2RpcG9kaT0iaHR0cDovL3NvZGlwb2RpLnNvdXJjZWZvcmdlLm5ldC9EVEQvc29kaXBvZGktMC5kdGQiCiAgIHhtbG5zOmlua3NjYXBlPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3Lmlua3NjYXBlLm9yZy9uYW1lc3BhY2VzL2lua3NjYXBlIgogICB3aWR0aD0iMjk3bW0iCiAgIGhlaWdodD0iMTEzbW0iCiAgIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyOTcgMTEzIgogICB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiCiAgIGlkPSJzdmc4IgogICBpbmtzY2FwZTp2ZXJzaW9uPSIwLjkyLjQgKDVkYTY4OWMzMTMsIDIwMTktMDEtMTQpIgogICBzb2RpcG9kaTpkb2NuYW1lPSJsb2dvLnN2ZyI+CiAgPHRpdGxlCiAgICAgaWQ9InRpdGxlMzc0MyI+cHJycmNsTG9nbzwvdGl0bGU+CiAgPGRlZnMKICAgICBpZD0iZGVmczIiPgogICAgPHBhdHRlcm4KICAgICAgIHBhdHRlcm5Vbml0cz0idXNlclNwYWNlT25Vc2UiCiAgICAgICB3aWR0aD0iMTAwLjAwMTI1IgogICAgICAgaGVpZ2h0PSIzOS44Mzk5OTkiCiAgICAgICBwYXR0ZXJuVHJhbnNmb3JtPSJtYXRyaXgoMC4yNjQ1ODMzMywwLDAsMC4yNjQ1ODMzMyw2NS4wMjc3NzQsMTI2LjY1ODIzKSIKICAgICAgIGlkPSJwYXR0ZXJuMzcxNyI+CiAgICAgIDx0ZXh0CiAgICAgICAgIGlkPSJ0ZXh0MzcxNSIKICAgICAgICAgeT0iMzAuMjQiCiAgICAgICAgIHg9Ii0yLjU1OTk5OTkiCiAgICAgICAgIHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXN0eWxlOm5vcm1hbDtmb250LXZhcmlhbnQ6bm9ybWFsO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zdHJldGNoOm5vcm1hbDtmb250LXNpemU6NDBweDtsaW5lLWhlaWdodDoxLjI1O2ZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OidBdmVuaXIgTmV4dCBMVCBQcm8nOy1pbmtzY2FwZS1mb250LXNwZWNpZmljYXRpb246J0F2ZW5pciBOZXh0IExUIFBybyBCb2xkJztsZXR0ZXItc3BhY2luZzowcHg7d29yZC1zcGFjaW5nOjBweDtmaWxsOiMwMDAwMDA7ZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5OjE7c3Ryb2tlOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjAuOTk5OTk5OTQiCiAgICAgICAgIHhtbDpzcGFjZT0icHJlc2VydmUiPjx0c3BhbgogICAgICAgICAgIHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXN0eWxlOm5vcm1hbDtmb250LXZhcmlhbnQ6bm9ybWFsO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zdHJldGNoOm5vcm1hbDtmb250LWZhbWlseTonQXZlbmlyIE5leHQgTFQgUHJvJzstaW5rc2NhcGUtZm9udC1zcGVjaWZpY2F0aW9uOidBdmVuaXIgTmV4dCBMVCBQcm8gQm9sZCc7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjAuOTk5OTk5OTQiCiAgICAgICAgICAgeT0iMzAuMjQiCiAgICAgICAgICAgeD0iLTIuNTU5OTk5OSIKICAgICAgICAgICBpZD0idHNwYW4zNzEzIgogICAgICAgICAgIHNvZGlwb2RpOnJvbGU9ImxpbmUiPnBycnJjbDwvdHNwYW4+PC90ZXh0PgogICAgPC9wYXR0ZXJuPgogIDwvZGVmcz4KICA8c29kaXBvZGk6bmFtZWR2aWV3CiAgICAgaWQ9ImJhc2UiCiAgICAgcGFnZWNvbG9yPSIjZmZmZmZmIgogICAgIGJvcmRlcmNvbG9yPSIjNjY2NjY2IgogICAgIGJvcmRlcm9wYWNpdHk9IjEuMCIKICAgICBpbmtzY2FwZTpwYWdlb3BhY2l0eT0iMC4wIgogICAgIGlua3NjYXBlOnBhZ2VzaGFkb3c9IjIiCiAgICAgaW5rc2NhcGU6em9vbT0iMC4zNSIKICAgICBpbmtzY2FwZTpjeD0iNzI0LjIzNTI4IgogICAgIGlua3NjYXBlOmN5PSI2MTkuNDIwODkiCiAgICAgaW5rc2NhcGU6ZG9jdW1lbnQtdW5pdHM9Im1tIgogICAgIGlua3NjYXBlOmN1cnJlbnQtbGF5ZXI9ImxheWVyMSIKICAgICBzaG93Z3JpZD0iZmFsc2UiCiAgICAgaW5rc2NhcGU6c25hcC10ZXh0LWJhc2VsaW5lPSJmYWxzZSIKICAgICBpbmtzY2FwZTp3aW5kb3ctd2lkdGg9IjEzNjYiCiAgICAgaW5rc2NhcGU6d2luZG93LWhlaWdodD0iNzE1IgogICAgIGlua3NjYXBlOndpbmRvdy14PSItOCIKICAgICBpbmtzY2FwZTp3aW5kb3cteT0iLTgiCiAgICAgaW5rc2NhcGU6d2luZG93LW1heGltaXplZD0iMSIKICAgICBoZWlnaHQ9IjIwOW1tIgogICAgIGlua3NjYXBlOnBhZ2VjaGVja2VyYm9hcmQ9ImZhbHNlIiAvPgogIDxtZXRhZGF0YQogICAgIGlkPSJtZXRhZGF0YTUiPgogICAgPHJkZjpSREY+CiAgICAgIDxjYzpXb3JrCiAgICAgICAgIHJkZjphYm91dD0iIj4KICAgICAgICA8ZGM6Zm9ybWF0PmltYWdlL3N2Zyt4bWw8L2RjOmZvcm1hdD4KICAgICAgICA8ZGM6dHlwZQogICAgICAgICAgIHJkZjpyZXNvdXJjZT0iaHR0cDovL3B1cmwub3JnL2RjL2RjbWl0eXBlL1N0aWxsSW1hZ2UiIC8+CiAgICAgICAgPGRjOnRpdGxlPnBycnJjbExvZ288L2RjOnRpdGxlPgogICAgICA8L2NjOldvcms+CiAgICA8L3JkZjpSREY+CiAgPC9tZXRhZGF0YT4KICA8ZwogICAgIGlua3NjYXBlOmxhYmVsPSJDYXBhIDEiCiAgICAgaW5rc2NhcGU6Z3JvdXBtb2RlPSJsYXllciIKICAgICBpZD0ibGF5ZXIxIgogICAgIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDAsLTE4NCkiPgogICAgPGcKICAgICAgIGFyaWEtbGFiZWw9IsKuIgogICAgICAgc3R5bGU9ImZvbnQtc3R5bGU6bm9ybWFsO2ZvbnQtdmFyaWFudDpub3JtYWw7Zm9udC13ZWlnaHQ6Ym9sZDtmb250LXN0cmV0Y2g6bm9ybWFsO2ZvbnQtc2l6ZTozMi4xNzk5NTgzNHB4O2xpbmUtaGVpZ2h0OjEuMjU7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWw7LWlua3NjYXBlLWZvbnQtc3BlY2lmaWNhdGlvbjonQXJpYWwgQm9sZCc7bGV0dGVyLXNwYWNpbmc6MHB4O3dvcmQtc3BhY2luZzowcHg7ZmlsbDojMDAwMDAwO2ZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eToxO3N0cm9rZTpub25lO3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDowLjgwNDQ5ODkxIgogICAgICAgaWQ9InRleHQzNzQxIgogICAgICAgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJtYXRyaXgoMS4wNDYyMzk1LDAsMCwxLjA0NjIzOTUsLTQuOTE2NTgyOCw1OC43NzE2MjUpIj4KICAgICAgPHBhdGgKICAgICAgICAgZD0ibSAyODYuMTYzMiwxNTYuODYxOTMgcSAwLDMuMjIxMTQgLTEuNjE4NDMsNi4wMDIzMiAtMS42MDI3MSwyLjc4MTE4IC00LjM4Mzg5LDQuMzgzODkgLTIuNzgxMTcsMS42MDI3MSAtNi4wMDIzMSwxLjYwMjcxIC0zLjIwNTQzLDAgLTUuOTg2NjEsLTEuNjAyNzEgLTIuNzgxMTcsLTEuNjAyNzEgLTQuMzk5NiwtNC4zODM4OSAtMS42MDI3MSwtMi43ODExOCAtMS42MDI3MSwtNi4wMDIzMiAwLC0zLjIwNTQyIDEuNjAyNzEsLTUuOTg2NiAxLjYxODQzLC0yLjc5Njg5IDQuMzk5NiwtNC4zOTk2IDIuNzgxMTgsLTEuNjAyNzIgNS45ODY2MSwtMS42MDI3MiAzLjIyMTE0LDAgNi4wMDIzMSwxLjYwMjcyIDIuNzgxMTgsMS42MDI3MSA0LjM4Mzg5LDQuMzk5NiAxLjYxODQzLDIuNzgxMTggMS42MTg0Myw1Ljk4NjYgeiBtIC0yLjMyNTUsMCBxIDAsLTQuMDA2NzggLTIuODQ0MDMsLTYuODM1MDkgLTIuODI4MzIsLTIuODQ0MDMgLTYuODM1MSwtMi44NDQwMyAtNC4wMDY3OCwwIC02Ljg1MDgxLDIuODQ0MDMgLTIuODI4MzIsMi44MjgzMSAtMi44MjgzMiw2LjgzNTA5IDAsNC4wMDY3OSAyLjgyODMyLDYuODUwODIgMi44NDQwMywyLjgyODMxIDYuODUwODEsMi44MjgzMSA0LjAwNjc4LDAgNi44MzUxLC0yLjgyODMxIDIuODQ0MDMsLTIuODQ0MDMgMi44NDQwMywtNi44NTA4MiB6IG0gLTE1LjExNTc5LC02LjQxMDg1IGggNS43MzUyIHEgMi40MzU1LDAgMy41MTk2OCwwLjk4OTkxIDEuMDk5OTEsMC45NzQyIDEuMDk5OTEsMi42MjQwNSAwLDEuMjg4NDYgLTAuODMyNzksMi4yMzEyMyAtMC44MzI3OCwwLjk0Mjc3IC0yLjYyNDA1LDEuMzY3MDIgMC43Mzg1MSwwLjI4MjgzIDEuMDg0MTksMC41OTcwOSAwLjQ4NzEsMC40Mzk5NiAxLjAyMTM0LDEuMzA0MTcgMC4wMzE0LDAuMDYyOCAyLjA3NDEsMy43MDgyMyBoIC0zLjc3MTA5IHEgLTEuODM4NDEsLTMuNjYxMDkgLTIuNDY2OTIsLTQuMzY4MTcgLTAuNjI4NTIsLTAuNzIyOCAtMS4yNTcwMywtMC43MjI4IC0wLjE0MTQyLDAgLTAuMzkyODIsMC4wNDcxIHYgNS4wNDM4MyBoIC0zLjE4OTcyIHogbSAzLjE4OTcyLDUuNDM2NjYgaCAxLjM4MjczIHEgMS4zODI3MywwIDEuOTQ4NCwtMC40Mzk5NiAwLjU2NTY2LC0wLjQ1NTY4IDAuNTY1NjYsLTEuMTYyNzYgMCwtMC43MDcwOCAtMC41NDk5NSwtMS4xNDcwNCAtMC41MzQyNCwtMC40NTU2NyAtMS44Mzg0MSwtMC40NTU2NyBoIC0xLjUwODQzIHoiCiAgICAgICAgIHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXN0eWxlOm5vcm1hbDtmb250LXZhcmlhbnQ6bm9ybWFsO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OjkwMDtmb250LXN0cmV0Y2g6bm9ybWFsO2ZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OkFyaWFsOy1pbmtzY2FwZS1mb250LXNwZWNpZmljYXRpb246J0FyaWFsIEhlYXZ5JztzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6MC44MDQ0OTg5MSIKICAgICAgICAgaWQ9InBhdGg4MjQiCiAgICAgICAgIGlua3NjYXBlOmNvbm5lY3Rvci1jdXJ2YXR1cmU9IjAiIC8+CiAgICA8L2c+CiAgICA8cGF0aAogICAgICAgaW5rc2NhcGU6Y29ubmVjdG9yLWN1cnZhdHVyZT0iMCIKICAgICAgIGlkPSJwYXRoNTI3MSIKICAgICAgIHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXN0eWxlOm5vcm1hbDtmb250LXZhcmlhbnQ6bm9ybWFsO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0Om5vcm1hbDtmb250LXN0cmV0Y2g6bm9ybWFsO2ZvbnQtc2l6ZToxMC41ODMzMzMwMnB4O2xpbmUtaGVpZ2h0OjEuMjU7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6J0F2ZW5pciBOZXh0IExUIFBybyc7LWlua3NjYXBlLWZvbnQtc3BlY2lmaWNhdGlvbjonQXZlbmlyIE5leHQgTFQgUHJvJztsZXR0ZXItc3BhY2luZzowcHg7d29yZC1zcGFjaW5nOjBweDtmaWxsOiMwMDAwMDA7ZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5OjE7c3Ryb2tlOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjIuNjMzMTMxNzQiCiAgICAgICBkPSJtIDYyLjA1MTMzNCwyNDIuODkzOTggYyAwLC0xNC42NDAzIC05LjU4NDU5MSwtMjcuNDg5OTEgLTI0Ljg1Njc1MywtMjcuNDg5OTEgLTcuNjg4NzQzLDAgLTEzLjU4Njk2MiwzLjY4NjMzIC0xNi43NDY3Miw3Ljg5OTQgaCAtMC4zMTU5NzYgdiAtNi40MjQ5MiBIIDMuNzAxMTQxMSB2IDc3LjczMDA2IEggMjAuOTc0NDkxIFYgMjYzLjUzNzcgaCAwLjIxMDY4NCBjIDMuMjY1MDksNC41Mjg5NSA5LjQ3OTI3NSw3LjI2NzQzIDE1LjkwNDEyNCw3LjI2NzQzIDE1Ljc5ODc4MywwIDI0Ljk2MjA4NywtMTMuMjcwOTggMjQuOTYyMDg3LC0yNy45MTExNSB6IG0gLTE2Ljc0NjcwMywwIGMgMCw2Ljg0NjA3IC00LjEwNzY4NiwxMy41ODY5NSAtMTIuMzIzMDU4LDEzLjU4Njk1IC03Ljc5NDA3NSwwIC0xMi42MzkwMzUsLTYuNjM1NDkgLTEyLjYzOTAzNSwtMTMuNDgxNjcgMCwtNi42MzU0OSA0Ljg0NDk2LC0xMy40ODE2NiAxMi42MzkwMzUsLTEzLjQ4MTY2IDguMjE1MzcyLDAgMTIuMzIzMDU4LDYuNjM1NDggMTIuMzIzMDU4LDEzLjM3NjM4IHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aAogICAgICAgaW5rc2NhcGU6Y29ubmVjdG9yLWN1cnZhdHVyZT0iMCIKICAgICAgIGlkPSJwYXRoNTI3MyIKICAgICAgIHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXN0eWxlOm5vcm1hbDtmb250LXZhcmlhbnQ6bm9ybWFsO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0Om5vcm1hbDtmb250LXN0cmV0Y2g6bm9ybWFsO2ZvbnQtc2l6ZToxMC41ODMzMzMwMnB4O2xpbmUtaGVpZ2h0OjEuMjU7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6J0F2ZW5pciBOZXh0IExUIFBybyc7LWlua3NjYXBlLWZvbnQtc3BlY2lmaWNhdGlvbjonQXZlbmlyIE5leHQgTFQgUHJvJztsZXR0ZXItc3BhY2luZzowcHg7d29yZC1zcGFjaW5nOjBweDtmaWxsOiMwMDAwMDA7ZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5OjE7c3Ryb2tlOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjIuNjMzMTMxNzQiCiAgICAgICBkPSJtIDEwNy41NzgyLDIxNS44MjUzNCBjIC0wLjg0MjY0LC0wLjMxNjQ4IC0yLjMxNzE1LC0wLjQyMDk4IC0zLjY4NjM4LC0wLjQyMDk4IC02LjQyNDg1MSwwIC0xMS41ODU3OSwzLjc5MTcyIC0xNC4yMTg5Miw5LjA1NzkyIGggLTAuMjEwNjgyIHYgLTcuNTgzNDMgSCA3Mi44MjA4MTkgdiA1Mi40NTIgaCAxNy4yNzMzNTYgdiAtMjYuOTYzMjQgYyAwLC00LjMxODM3IDMuMDU0NDI3LC0xMS45MDE4IDEyLjMyMzA2NSwtMTEuOTAxOCAxLjM2OTIxLDAgMi44NDM3NywwLjEwNTQ1IDQuNDIzNjYsMC41MjY0NyB6IiAvPgogICAgPHBhdGgKICAgICAgIGlua3NjYXBlOmNvbm5lY3Rvci1jdXJ2YXR1cmU9IjAiCiAgICAgICBpZD0icGF0aDUyNzUiCiAgICAgICBzdHlsZT0iZm9udC1zdHlsZTpub3JtYWw7Zm9udC12YXJpYW50Om5vcm1hbDtmb250LXdlaWdodDpub3JtYWw7Zm9udC1zdHJldGNoOm5vcm1hbDtmb250LXNpemU6MTAuNTgzMzMzMDJweDtsaW5lLWhlaWdodDoxLjI1O2ZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OidBdmVuaXIgTmV4dCBMVCBQcm8nOy1pbmtzY2FwZS1mb250LXNwZWNpZmljYXRpb246J0F2ZW5pciBOZXh0IExUIFBybyc7bGV0dGVyLXNwYWNpbmc6MHB4O3dvcmQtc3BhY2luZzowcHg7ZmlsbDojMDAwMDAwO2ZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eToxO3N0cm9rZTpub25lO3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDoyLjYzMzEzMTc0IgogICAgICAgZD0ibSAxNDkuMzM4MDIsMjE1LjgyNTM0IGMgLTAuODQyNjMsLTAuMzE2NDggLTIuMzE3MTYsLTAuNDIwOTggLTMuNjg2MzgsLTAuNDIwOTggLTYuNDI0ODUsMCAtMTEuNTg1NzgsMy43OTE3MiAtMTQuMjE4OTEsOS4wNTc5MiBoIC0wLjIxMDY5IHYgLTcuNTgzNDMgaCAtMTYuNjQxMzcgdiA1Mi40NTIgaCAxNy4yNzMzNiB2IC0yNi45NjMyNCBjIDAsLTQuMzE4MzcgMy4wNTQ0NCwtMTEuOTAxOCAxMi4zMjMwNSwtMTEuOTAxOCAxLjM2OTIzLDAgMi44NDM3OCwwLjEwNTQ1IDQuNDIzNjcsMC41MjY0NyB6IiAvPgogICAgPHBhdGgKICAgICAgIGlua3NjYXBlOmNvbm5lY3Rvci1jdXJ2YXR1cmU9IjAiCiAgICAgICBpZD0icGF0aDUyNzciCiAgICAgICBzdHlsZT0iZm9udC1zdHlsZTpub3JtYWw7Zm9udC12YXJpYW50Om5vcm1hbDtmb250LXdlaWdodDpub3JtYWw7Zm9udC1zdHJldGNoOm5vcm1hbDtmb250LXNpemU6MTAuNTgzMzMzMDJweDtsaW5lLWhlaWdodDoxLjI1O2ZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OidBdmVuaXIgTmV4dCBMVCBQcm8nOy1pbmtzY2FwZS1mb250LXNwZWNpZmljYXRpb246J0F2ZW5pciBOZXh0IExUIFBybyc7bGV0dGVyLXNwYWNpbmc6MHB4O3dvcmQtc3BhY2luZzowcHg7ZmlsbDojMDAwMDAwO2ZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eToxO3N0cm9rZTpub25lO3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDoyLjYzMzEzMTc0IgogICAgICAgZD0ibSAxOTEuMDk3ODQsMjE1LjgyNTM0IGMgLTAuODQyNjQsLTAuMzE2NDggLTIuMzE3MTUsLTAuNDIwOTggLTMuNjg2MzgsLTAuNDIwOTggLTYuNDI0ODMsMCAtMTEuNTg1NzgsMy43OTE3MiAtMTQuMjE4OSw5LjA1NzkyIGggLTAuMjEwNjggdiAtNy41ODM0MyBoIC0xNi42NDE0IHYgNTIuNDUyIGggMTcuMjczMzQgdiAtMjYuOTYzMjQgYyAwLC00LjMxODM3IDMuMDU0NDUsLTExLjkwMTggMTIuMzIzMDUsLTExLjkwMTggMS4zNjkyNCwwIDIuODQzNzksMC4xMDU0NSA0LjQyMzY3LDAuNTI2NDcgeiIgLz4KICAgIDxwYXRoCiAgICAgICBpbmtzY2FwZTpjb25uZWN0b3ItY3VydmF0dXJlPSIwIgogICAgICAgaWQ9InBhdGg1Mjc5IgogICAgICAgc3R5bGU9ImZvbnQtc3R5bGU6bm9ybWFsO2ZvbnQtdmFyaWFudDpub3JtYWw7Zm9udC13ZWlnaHQ6bm9ybWFsO2ZvbnQtc3RyZXRjaDpub3JtYWw7Zm9udC1zaXplOjEwLjU4MzMzMzAycHg7bGluZS1oZWlnaHQ6MS4yNTtmb250LWZhbWlseTonQXZlbmlyIE5leHQgTFQgUHJvJzstaW5rc2NhcGUtZm9udC1zcGVjaWZpY2F0aW9uOidBdmVuaXIgTmV4dCBMVCBQcm8nO2xldHRlci1zcGFjaW5nOjBweDt3b3JkLXNwYWNpbmc6MHB4O2ZpbGw6IzAwMDAwMDtmaWxsLW9wYWNpdHk6MTtzdHJva2U6bm9uZTtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6Mi42MzMxMzE3NCIKICAgICAgIGQ9Im0gMjQyLjM4MTM5LDIyMi4yNTAxNSBjIC00LjEwNzY5LC00LjIxMjk3IC0xMi4wMDcwOSwtNy4wNTY3NiAtMTkuNDg1MTcsLTcuMDU2NzYgLTE2LjMyNTQyLDAgLTI5LjI4MDQ0LDEwLjg0ODQ3IC0yOS4yODA0NCwyNy45MTExNiAwLDE3LjM3ODY3IDEyLjg0OTcsMjcuOTExMjggMjkuMzg1NzcsMjcuOTExMjggNy42ODg3MiwwIDE1LjA2MTUsLTIuNTI3ODEgMTkuMzc5ODQsLTYuNzQwODkgbCAtOS41ODQ2LC0xMS42OTExMSBjIC0yLjEwNjUyLDIuNTI3ODEgLTUuODk4MjEsMy44OTcxIC05LjM3Mzk1LDMuODk3MSAtNy41ODM0MSwwIC0xMi4zMjMwNSwtNi4xMDg5MyAtMTIuMzIzMDUsLTEzLjM3NjM4IDAsLTcuMjY3NDQgNC44NDQ5NSwtMTMuNDgxNTcgMTIuMTEyNCwtMTMuNDgxNTcgMy40NzU3MywwIDcuMjY3NDQsMS42ODUxNyA5LjE2MzMsNC4yMTI5OCB6IiAvPgogICAgPHBhdGgKICAgICAgIGlua3NjYXBlOmNvbm5lY3Rvci1jdXJ2YXR1cmU9IjAiCiAgICAgICBpZD0icGF0aDUyODEiCiAgICAgICBzdHlsZT0iZm9udC1zdHlsZTpub3JtYWw7Zm9udC12YXJpYW50Om5vcm1hbDtmb250LXdlaWdodDpub3JtYWw7Zm9udC1zdHJldGNoOm5vcm1hbDtmb250LXNpemU6MTAuNTgzMzMzMDJweDtsaW5lLWhlaWdodDoxLjI1O2ZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OidBdmVuaXIgTmV4dCBMVCBQcm8nOy1pbmtzY2FwZS1mb250LXNwZWNpZmljYXRpb246J0F2ZW5pciBOZXh0IExUIFBybyc7bGV0dGVyLXNwYWNpbmc6MHB4O3dvcmQtc3BhY2luZzowcHg7ZmlsbDojMDAwMDAwO2ZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eToxO3N0cm9rZTpub25lO3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDoyLjYzMzEzMTc0IgogICAgICAgZD0ibSAyNjcuMDE3NjQsMjY5LjMzMDU1IHYgLTc5LjYyNTkxIGggLTE3LjQ4NCB2IDc5LjYyNTkxIHoiIC8+CiAgPC9nPgo8L3N2Zz4K"/>
                    </li>
                    <ItemMenu url={'/cv'} children={'cv'}/>

                    <ItemMenu url={'/contact'} children={'contact'}/>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes crear un binding en el constructor para que pueda tomar la funcion. Ya que `this` en este caso es `undefined` ya que en `JSX` es diferente y por esto no invoca la función.

```
constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state  = {
           menuMobile: true
       }
this.openMenuMobile = this.openMenuMobile.bind(this)
   }
```

Comment: Genial! justo lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada!!! @adrian.